# Amortized Analysis - Potential Method

Tags: ds.algorithms, amortized-analysis

I read about [Potential Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_method) when I was trying to understand some calculations.

I just can't understand how do you perform the calculation it self. How can you even define $O(n)-O(n)$ as it is used in the Wikipedia page? I just don't understand where is the calculation done.

Is there any good and simple example of this kind of analysis?

Shay

Comment: The Wikipedia article uses variable-length arrays with size doubling as an example.  This is a good example, but the explanation in the Wikipedia article is next to incorrect.  It is correct that the amortized cost of the insertion when the expansion occurs is O(1), but not because it is O(n)−O(n).

Comment: Yes I understand that, I actually proved that once in a much simpler way.
Do you know any better explanation online (article, video, doesn't matter)?

Comment: indeed. In fact the original explanation in the table expansion article is essentially a potential method, but correctly explained.

Comment: http://theory.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/algorithms/notes/14-amortize.pdf

Comment: @jbapple make this an answer so it can be accepted, preventing Community from bumping it up again and again ?

Comment: @Suresh sure, no prob.

Comment: Note that $\cal{O}(n) - \cal{O}(n)$ is abuse of notation and should be handled with utmost care.

Comment: Thank you all, and yes, I do know that $O(n) - O(n)$ is actually $O(n)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://theory.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/algorithms/notes/15-amortize.pdf specifically for amortization, and http://theory.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/algorithms/ generally